# SQL: list of sales with employee and employee's title for that given time

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Let's say I have three tables:

```
+------------+ +------------+ +-------------+
| SALES      | | EMPLOYEES  | | ASSIGNMENTS |
+------------+ +------------+ +-------------+
| SaleID     | | EmployeeID | | EmployeeID  |
| SaleDate   | | Name       | | AssignDate  |
| EmployeeID | +------------| | ReleaseDate |
+------------+                | Description |
                              +-------------+
```

And I want my output to look like:

```
+--------+--------------+--------------------+
| SALEID |     NAME     |    DESCRIPTION     |
+--------+--------------+--------------------+
|  91    | John Smith   | District Sales     |
|  178   | Jane Thomas  | District Sales     |
|  23    | John Smith   | Junior Sales Assoc |
|  42    | Jane Thomas  | Junior Sales Assoc |
|  56    | John Smith   | Junior Sales Assoc |
|  73    | Suzy Johnson | Regional Sales     |
|  156   | John Smith   | Regional Sales     |
+--------+--------------+--------------------+
```

How do I begin to grab the appropriate Description based on whether the SaleDate is between AssignDate and ReleaseDate? To complicate matters, John's current assignment will have NULL as the ReleaseDate. I could just use some help getting started in the right direction. Thank you everyone!

**EDIT**

Here is some sample data:

```
+--------+------------+------------+
| SaleID |  SaleDate  | EmployeeID |
+--------+------------+------------+
|  23    | 2016-05-30 |     15     |
|  42    | 2016-06-12 |     62     |
|  56    | 2016-06-15 |     15     |
|  73    | 2016-10-28 |     49     |
|  91    | 2017-09-02 |     15     |
|  156   | 2018-02-04 |     15     |
|  178   | 2018-03-30 |     62     |
+--------+------------+------------+

+------------+--------------+
| EmployeeID |    Name      |
+------------+--------------+
|    15      | John Smith   |
|    49      | Suzy Johnson |
|    62      | Jane Thomas  |
+------------+--------------+

+------------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
| EmployeeID | AssignDate | Release Date |    Description     |
+------------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
|   15       | 2018-01-12 |    NULL      | Regional Sales     |
|   15       | 2017-07-23 |  2018-01-11  | District Sales     |
|   15       | 2016-01-01 |  2017-07-22  | Junior Sales Assoc |
|   49       | 2018-02-10 |    NULL      | Regional Sales     |
|   62       | 2017-09-14 |    NULL      | District Sales     |
|   62       | 2016-04-28 |  2017-09-13  | Junior Sales Assoc |
+------------+------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data sample  (coherent with the expected  result) and the query you tried ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just some help getting started that you're after:

- Review the `IsNull` function for dealing with John's release date
- review `between` comparisons for placing sales dates within assignment dates.
- Note that your sample data is inconsistent because Suzy's sale (73) is dated before her AssignDate.

Since I'm now leaving my desk, I'll also leave you with a worked solution.  I'd highly recommend trying to solve it yourself first.

```
-- for convenience I'm using Common Table Expressions (CTEs) to hold the test data
;with sales (saleId, saleDate, employeeId)
as
(
      select  23  , '2016-05-30', 15     
union select  42  , '2016-06-12', 62     
union select  56  , '2016-06-15', 15     
union select  73  , '2016-10-28', 49     
union select  91  , '2017-09-02', 15     
union select  156 , '2018-02-04', 15     
union select  178 , '2018-03-30', 62     
)
, employees (employeeId, name)
as
(
      select   15      , 'John Smith' 
union select   49      , 'Suzy Johnson' 
union select   62      , 'Jane Thomas'
)
, assignments (employeeId, assignDate, releaseDate, description)
as
(
      select 15     , '2018-01-12',   NULL      , 'Regional Sales'
union select 15     , '2017-07-23', '2018-01-11', 'District Sales'
union select 15     , '2016-01-01', '2017-07-22', 'Junior Sales Assoc'
union select 49     , '2018-02-10',   NULL      , 'Regional Sales'
union select 62     , '2017-09-14',   NULL      , 'District Sales'
union select 62     , '2016-04-28', '2017-09-13', 'Junior Sales Assoc'
)

SELECT s.saleDate, s.saleId, e.name, a.description
FROM sales s
JOIN employees e
    ON s.employeeId = e.employeeId
JOIN assignments a
    ON s.EmployeeID = a.employeeId
    -- NOTE the use of IsNull allowing me to substitute the current date if there is no release date.
    and s.saleDate between a.assignDate and ISNULL(a.releaseDate, getdate())
```

Comment: Ooh passing today's date int the IsNull() command looks perfect! I'll give it a go and see what comes back.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT 
  SaleID
,  Name
, Description
FROM SALES AS S
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES AS E ON S.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN ASSIGNMENTS AS A ON A.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
WHERE A.AssignDate IS NOT NULL 
AND A.ReleaseDate IS NOT NULL 
AND S.SaleDate >= A.AssignDate AND S.SaleDate <= A.ReleaseDate
```

Comment: I started with a simple join with the same date filters, but it doesn't return sales for an employee's current assignment (any date is not less than NULL).

Comment: I have added the NULL check for the release date. Check now with updated query